# Unable to get location listener

Tags: android

I am trying to use google fusedapi,

```
public class MapDirection extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener {
```

but i am not getting location listener reference when try to create request

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your LocationListener package. It should be com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener.